# how to increase the radius in circlize plot

Tags: r, plot, circlize

I have drawn the following plot using the `circlize`package. The red circle is the unit circle drawn afterwards, using `plotrix`. I want to plot the first track outside the red unit circle. For this reason I changed `canvas.xlim` and `canvas.ylim` to `c(-1.2, 1.2)`. However, this does not work. Any ideas how to increase the circle radius for the `circlize` plot?

**NOTE**: Alternatively, it would be sufficient for me, if the tracks would be outside of the unit circle instead of inside.

[image]

```
library(circlize)
set.seed(2)
n = 10
a = data.frame(factor = "dummy",
               x = rnorm(n, 100, sd=10))
circos.par(track.height = 0.2,
           canvas.xlim=c(-1.2, 1.2),   # bigger canvas?
           canvas.ylim=c(-1.2, 1.2))   # bigger canvas?
circos.initialize(factors = a$factor, 
                  x = a$x, xlim = c(0, 360))

lim <- c(-1.2, 1.2)
plot(NULL, asp=1, xlim=lim, ylim=lim)
circos.trackHist(a$factor, a$x, col = "blue", bg.col = grey(.95))
plotrix::draw.circle(0,0,1, border="red", lwd=2)  # unit circle
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to adjust `xlim` and `ylim` to make two plots fit. But if you just want to put the red circle inside the track, you can use `draw.sector()` function directly:

```
circos.initialize(factors = a$factor, 
                  x = a$x, xlim = c(0, 360))
circos.trackHist(a$factor, a$x, col = "blue", bg.col = grey(.95))
draw.sector(0, 360, rou1 = circlize:::get_most_inside_radius(),
    border = "red")
```

Here `circlize:::get_most_inside_radius()` returns the distance between the bottom border of the last track to the center of the circle.

Comment: SO now has a [`circlize`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/circlize/info) tag for your convenience!